# Can Google Analytics Pro Give Video Specific Data?

Tags: php, google-analytics, jwplayer

I now have Google Analytics Pro integrated into my videos correctly which is great news. However looking at the user guide it appears that the data collected is aggregated across all the videos that have the plugin installed.

What I am curious to know is if it is possible to have data broken out by a specific video instead, so that I can see all the starts, percentages and times for just video A as opposed to having it report on videos A, B and C all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is aggregated by category (video starts, seconds played, percentage played), but broken down on a video-by-video basis thereafter. Thus, clicking on 'video starts' from the overview page will yield another page with video-by-video stats.

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a custom tracking system using JW Player API that could communicate with  Google Analytics API to maximum utilize all the available features in Google Analytics. This will help you to generate custom reports with required tracking fields.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Analytics, all event driven tracking in a site are recorded under "Event Tracking" section under "Content" menu. So all video related data comes under this section. We also have different sub sections under "Event Tracking".
Among that "Categories" section is what we are concerned with. Under "Categories" we have the sub sections as follows

1. Video Plays
2. Seconds Played
3. Percentage Played

**Video Plays**
Clicking on “Video Plays” from the “Categories” page will bring up a report detailing which videos were started, listed by the URL of the video file.
This section we can see table list with columns like "Total Events, Unique Events, Event Value and Average Value".

**Total Events**
The total number of times the videos were started on the specified site. This includes views that occurred after the viewer pressed stop, or completed the video and pressed play again.

**Unique Events**
The total number of viewers for a video

**Event Value**
The total number of seconds all viewers spent watching the specified video, across all sites. This includes time spent re-watching a section.

**Average Value**
The number of seconds the average viewer spent watching the specified video, across all sites.

**Seconds Played**
Clicking on “Seconds Played” from the “Categories” page will bring up a report detailing how much time each viewer spent watching the videos, listed by the URL of the video file.
Table list items in this section are same as "Video Plays"

**Percentage Played**
Clicking on “Percentage Played” from the “Categories” page will bring up a report detailing what percentage of each video the average viewer watched, listed by the URL of the video file.
Table list items in this section are same as "Video Plays"

**Engagement Details**
It is just the report of particular percentage of videos played by the viewers. For example (20% played by 10 users, 50% played by 30 users).